# Push row to top in UItableview in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I have uitableview and it has 1 button "TOP" in each row. I want to when user click on this button, this row has been push on top in Uitableview ( with animation). Can i reuse `BVReorderTableView` to do that? How can i do that? Thanks much

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i am assuming your `-cellForRowAtIndexPath` loads cell contents from an array such as the one i named `arrObjects` which:

1. is an `NSMutableArray` object
2. has many `NSString` objects

something like:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
         cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    //...
    [cell.textLabel setText:[arrObjects objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

    UIButton *btnUp = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    [btnUp setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 30, 30)];
    //[btnUp setTag:100];
    [btnUp setTitle:@"\u261D" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [btnUp addTarget:self
              action:@selector(moveToTop:)
    forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [cell setAccessoryView:btnUp];

    return cell;
}
```

---

```
- (void)moveToTop:(UIButton *)sender
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)sender.superview; //iOS6 prior
    //UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)sender.superview.superview; //iOS7

    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:cell];

    //uncomment lines for safety, incase indexPath ever comes nil... prevent the crash
    //if (indexPath == nil) {
    //    return;
    //}

    //1. move and animate row to top
    [self.tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:indexPath.row
                                                           inSection:indexPath.section]
                           toIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:0
                                                           inSection:indexPath.section]];


    //2. make appropriate changes to the datasource
    //so that it reflects logically and is not just an aestehtical change

    //PRE-NOTE:
    //arrObjects is an object of a category on NSMutableArray
    //with a custom instance method named -moveObjectFromIndexPath:toIndex:

    //uncomment the following line when you are ready with the category
    //[arrObjects moveObjectFromIndex:indexPath.row toIndex:0];
}
```

the **category** is easy to create, follow:
http://www.icab.de/blog/2009/11/15/moving-objects-within-an-nsmutablearray/

---

other links to try:

1. http://adeem.me/blog/2009/05/29/iphone-sdk-tutorial-add-delete-reorder-uitableview-row/
2. http://learn-iphone-app-development.com/2011/01/31/tables-part-iii-%E2%80%94-re-ordering-moving-cells-and-swipe-to-delete/

Answer (score 2):

have you tried

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)sourceIndexPath toIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)destinationIndexPath;
```

you can use animations if you want so..

Answer (score 1):

You can easy do that like this:

```
[self.tableView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, 0) animated:YES];
```

or:

```
[self.tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0] atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionBottom animated:YES];
```

or:

```
[self.tableView scrollRectToVisible:CGRectMake(0.f, 0.f, CGRectGetWidth(self.tableView.frame), CGRectGetHeight(self.tableView.frame)) animated:YES];
```

**Edit**
Sorry, I misunderstood what you meant. 
You should do that like this:

```
[tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:indexPath toIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0]];
```

If you want to tableView scroll to the top immediately after move the cell, you can try the above code.

**Edit**

```
    // A more detailed description
- (void)buttonHandle:(UIButton *)sender {
    // Assuming button is added directly on the cell.
    UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)sender.superview;
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [tableView indexPathForCell:cell];
    [tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:indexPath toIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0]];
}
```

Comment: i think he wants to rearrange the selected row to go to the top of the table rather than simply auto-scroll to the topmost row.

Comment: @staticVoidMan: yes, correct, I want to rearrage row to top of the tableview.

Comment: @JosonDaniel: check my answer, hope it helps.